# Remove n lines after nth occurrence of a pattern and paste content of a file after nth occurrence in unix

Tags: string, file, unix, sed, paste

I have a file that contains two repeated strings, which are my markers to recognize. The marker is "(CO)VARIANCES" and each of theme following 3 different lines. I want to remove the 3 lines after the first string and replace it with the content of another file. Structure of file is like:

```
cat file1.txt
```

```
Something1
Something2
Something3
(CO)VARIANCES
44.572      0.28723E-01   0.0000
0.28723E-01  0.64501E-03   0.0000
0.0000       0.0000      0.0000
Something4
Something5
Something6
(CO)VARIANCES
34.891      0.38642E-01   1.7538
0.38642E-01  0.17122E-02  0.54735E-02
1.7538      0.54735E-02  0.23285
```

I want to remove three lines after `(CO)VARIANCES` and replace it with another file that contains something. The command

```
sed -e '/(CO)VARIANCES/{n;N;N;d}' file1.txt
```

is removing 3 lines after both markers and I don't know how to indicate the number of occurrence in this command. And I don't know how to conditionally paste the second content of the second file after those markers. Does somebody have an idea about that?

Comment: Please show the contents of the other file and the expected output. Do I understand correct that you want to replace only the 3 lines following the first occurrence of `(CO)VARIANCES` and leave the data after the second (and maybe any later) `(CO)VARIANCES` unchanged?

Comment: @Bodo, yes that's true, you understand perfectly. I want to do the same with the second marker also. The other file has content the same as the 3 lines that I want to remove. In fact, I want to replace those 3 lines with new values.

Answer (score 0):

To perform the replacement on the Nth occurrence, consider the following script (N is the n-th occurrence)

```
awk -v N=3 '

  # Delete if needed
DEL > 0 { DEL-- ; next } ;

  # Find matching line
$1 == "(CO)VARIANCES" && (--N) == 0 {
  print
  DEL = 3 ;

  # Include second file here.
  while ( getline v < "file2.txt" ) print v ;
  next
}
   # Print all other lines
{ print }
'
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -En '/\(CO\)VARIANCES/{n;:a;s/[^\n]*/&/3;tb;N;ba;:b;p}' file2 |
sed -Ee '/\(CO\)VARIANCES/{n;:a;R /dev/stdin' -e 's/[^\n]*/&/3;tb;N;ba;:b;d}' file1
```

The solution consists of two sed invocations piped together.

The first sed invocation prepares a file consisting of the lines from file2 following the marker (in the this case 3).

The second sed invocation reads in the required number of lines from the first invocation and deletes the same number of lines from file1 following the marker.